# ggplot2 , ggridges , Error in -x : invalid argument to unary operator

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggridges, ridgeline-plot

I'm trying to plot a joyplot graph( density distributions across time) from the ggridges package. The file 'Dados empilhados' is a pooled data set.

```
library(ggridges)
library(ggplot2)    
library(XLConnect)

data = loadWorkbook('Dados empilhados.xls')

data = readWorksheet(data, sheet = 'Sheet1', header = T)
ggplot(data[data$Time>0,], aes(x = betas.dyn, y = Time, group = Time)) +
  geom_density_ridges(scale = 10, size = 0.25, rel_min_height = 0.03) +
  theme_ridges() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0.0, 1.3), expand = c(0.01, 0)) +
  scale_y_reverse(breaks=c(2016, 2012, 2008, 2004, 2001), expand = c(0.01, 0))
```

but i'm getting the following error:

```
Error in -x : invalid argument to unary operator
```

Obs.:
Dados empilhados:

```
Time      Country    betas    betas.dyn  
2001-Q1   Angola     10.02    12.23
2001-Q2   Angola     14.53    13.45
2001-Q3   Angola     13.32    11.74
   .         .         .        .
   .         .         .        .
   .         .         .        .
```

Comment: This might be the cause `data[data$Time>0,]`

Comment: Please provide a minimally reproducible example, with data.